# SalesforceMobileSDK Hybrid - Spring '23 Issue on Log-in

Tags: mobilesdk, spring23

As of Spring 23' Release version, we've been experiencing issue on re-direct to home page on both Android and iOS devices.

salesforce-mobilesdk-cordova-plugin: 9.1.1 / 10.2.0

We've tried isolating the issue by creating from the sample app and did the following steps:

1. Install any sample app following the instructions:
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_samples_build.htm
2. Update "Consumer Key" in bootconfig.json (using the key from **XXXX_app** connected app)
3. Build the app and run it
4. Login using system admin account in Sandbox
5. Observe redirect behavior

Observation:

- iOS: The page will be blank after login and shows timeout error in the log when accessing "https://XXXXX--XXXX.sandbox.file.force.com/secur/contentDoor?"
- Android: The page is redirected slowly, takes around ~30 seconds
- This app was working fine previously, and it's still working fine in the non-preview sandbox and in Production environment (Winter '23 Release)

Below is the error log found on iOS device when trying to re-direct to the home page:

> 2023-01-27 13:08:26.931831+0700 testlogin[93658:937004] [SalesforceHybrid] CLASS: SFHybridViewController webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler: Loading URL 'https://mydomain--sit2.sandbox.file.force.com/secur/contentDoor?[content]'
> 2023-01-27 13:08:47.504193+0700 testlogin[93658:937004] [Process] 0x160029e18 - [pageProxyID=21, webPageID=22, PID=93680] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, isMainFrame=1, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1001, isMainFrame=1

We're originally building the app using SF Mobile SDK 9.1.1 version, but has also tried replicating the issue using 10.2.0 version. To narrow down the issue, we've tried connecting the app to the Non-preview sandbox and was not able to replicate this issue on the non-preview sandbox.

Comment: Update on latest observation:  

The aforementioned url `https://mydomain--sit2.sandbox.file.force.com/secur/contentDoor?[content]` has been observed to take 20-22 seconds to load.

From PC browser, it’s taking 600 ms, we are currently understanding this is the cause of the issue, as the iOS NSURLRequest timeout was previously configured as 20 seconds.   We’ve implemented a workaround in the mean-time by increasing the timeout config, but would like to ultimately understand why this request is taking a long time to get the response.

Comment: Now that the Spring '23 update has been released, the same behavior has been observed also on the Production environment of Salesforce.

Workaround has been applied to said environment, but log-in process is now taking more than 20 seconds everytime on mobile devices, any help or suggestion would be appreciated